how to format a number in excel to apper in a specific output?
how to format a cell in excel, so that when i type 10801801 i get 108 018 01, and when i type 108018 i get 108 018.
To format a cell in Excel to display numbers in the desired format,
I Select the cell or range of cells I want to format.
Right-click on the selected cells and choose "Format Cells" from the context menu.
In the Format Cells dialog box, switch to the "Number" tab.
In the "Category" list, select "Custom."
In the "Type" input field, enter the custom format code based on my requirements.
For my specific examples:
To format a 9-digit number as "XXX XXX XX", I enter the following custom format code in the "Type" field: 000\ 000\ 00
To format a 6-digit number as "XXX XXX", I enter the following custom format code in the "Type" field: 000\ 000.
I want just one and only custom format to do both tasks.

On google sheet, I attempted to reproduce your use case by custom formatting with this format,
[>=10000000]###\ ###\ ##;[>=100000]###\ ###;###
I was able to get desired outputs as you wanted. Please try this and let us know if it gets solved.

Add semicolon ";"
000\ 000\ 00;000\ 000
When you type a 9-digit number (e.g., 10801801), Excel will display it as 108 018 01.
When you type a 6-digit number (e.g., 108018), Excel will display it as 108 018.

TitoSenpai For six digit number i got 001 080 18, instead of the desired 108 018
